# Is ShortBuffer.capacity the same as it size or length

Tags: java

Can I use capacity to find the actual size or length of a ShortBuffer?  From what I have read it returns the number of elements contained in the buffer.  But the word "capacity" is so ambiguous.  If I put an array of 5 shorts in this buffer, will capacity always return 5?

Comment: Capacity isn't an ambiguous word. ca·pac·i·ty (noun) 1. the maximum amount that something can contain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The capacity is the amount of data the buffer effectively *can* hold at the moment. It doesn't mean that much data *has* been written.

If you put an array of 5 shorts in a buffer with a larger capacity, that won't change the capacity, but it *will* change the position. For example:

```
import java.nio.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ShortBuffer buffer = ShortBuffer.allocate(100);
        short[] data = new short[5];
        buffer.put(data);
        System.out.println(buffer.capacity()); // Prints 100
        System.out.println(buffer.position()); // Prints 5
    }
}
```

Of course, if you only initialize the buffer with the capacity you need, that will be the same. But you do need to understand the difference between the two. If you imagine that the buffer is an empty sheet of lined paper, the capacity is how many lines are available on the paper in total, whereas the position will effectively show the position of the next *blank* line to write in.

Comment: Thanx! So to clearify. If I allocate exactly what I need, and then use it as a read only buffer, capacity will return that number - in all cases? Some buffers, as known in some languages, can sometimes allocate more memory than needed. And therefore it is useless to use its capacity as a size reference.

Comment: @Espen: I believe so. If you try to write beyond the capacity of an NIO buffer, it will throw an exception.

Comment: @Espen - the javadoc clearly states that a nio Buffer does not allocate more memory; see the quoted text in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *capacity* returns the maximum number of elements in the buffer. If you initialise it with a capacity of 5, its capacity will always be 5. Of course, that doesn't mean it will necessarily contain 5 elements.

Answer (score 2):

> If I put an array of 5 shorts in this buffer, will capacity always return 5?

I think the real answer is no.  The capacity of a buffer is determined by the parameter you provide when you allocate the buffer, not the number of elements that you put into it.

The Buffer javadoc says this:

> A buffer is a linear, finite sequence
>   of elements of a specific primitive
>   type. Aside from its content, the
>   essential properties of a buffer are
>   its capacity, limit, and position:
>
> - A buffer's capacity is the number of elements it contains. The capacity
>     of a buffer is never negative and
>     never changes.
> - A buffer's limit is the index of the first element that should not be
>     read or written. A buffer's limit is
>     never negative and is never greater
>     than its capacity.
> - A buffer's position is the index of the next element to be read or
>     written. A buffer's position is never
>     negative and is never greater than its
>     limit.

While the wording leaves something to be desired, I discern a distinction between the number of elements it *can* contain (`capacity`), and the number of elements it *currently* contains; typically `(limit - position)` when reading or `position` when writing.

This is reinforced by the javadocs for the [`allocate(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ShortBuffer.html#allocate%28int%29) and [`put(short)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ShortBuffer.html#put%28short%29) methods.  The former states that the parameter gives the buffer capacity, and the latter does NOT state that `put` will update the buffer capacity.

(On the other hand, you could argue that a buffer literally does "contain" capacity elements at all times, but that some of those elements are not "valid" data.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According to the `Buffer` (which is a superclass of `ShortBuffer`) [reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html):

"A buffer's capacity is the number of elements it contains."

Comment: That's what it literally says, but in practice I think it *means* something else; see my answer.